# How can I write an .htaccess that will rewrite differently based on the request url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, conditional-statements, localhost

I would like to have one .htaccess file that can rewrite correctly on both my localhost development environment and on my hosted production site. Right now I have to keep two separate file copies for every site I work on. I would like to be able to synchronize the two sites without blowing away either one of their .htaccess files.

Below is the .htaccess file that I'm using with a little pseudo code in the comments to demonstrate what I want to do.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)

## IF the url looks like its from localhost then use this rule
  ## The incoming url might look like: http://localhost/mysite/about
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/index.php/$1 [L]
## Else do this rewrite
  ## The incoming url might look like: http://www.mysite.com/about
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Here is my server configurations:

**Development**: xampp on windows

**Production**: Dreamhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty on this, but I think:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]

#Do your live stuff here

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]

#Do your local stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RewriteCond to check %{HTTP_HOST}. eg:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^localhost$
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a separate [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) for your development environment with the same settings as your production server has.

Just add another `<VirtualHost>` container to your *httpd.conf* or *httpd-vhosts.conf* configuration file and adjust the settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com.local
    DocumentRoot /absolute/filesystem/path/to/your/localhost/mysite
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That's a good idea however I prefer to develop and debug on my local machine then upload changes.